# How to take avi snapshot in .NET

Tags: .net, image, movie, avi

I'm looking easy way to take snapshot of AVI file in .NET (C#)

I need take pictures of given time - I mean:

```
TakeSnapshot (file_name, second)
```

Any advice(s) how to deal with that?

Comment: Check http://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/steganodotnet4.aspx

Answer (score 1):

1)  Most web cameras you buy will have their own software, and they can usually generate .avi output.

3) The "best" Win32 API for Video Capture has always been Microsoft DirectShow.  Here's a good link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318627%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

4) The "annointed" .Net successor to DirectShow was supposed to be Windows Media Framework.  But I've never used it, and it doesn't sound like it's ready for Prime Time yet:

http://www.jasonrowland.com/2011/02/video-capture-with-c/

5) Here's one other library you might wish to consider - it can be used with C#, and it supports .avi output:

http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/